# Storing the name of a radio button when checked, then removing it when it's cleared

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the HTML code I currently have:

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8bw6vfwp/1/)**

```
<div class="container-cell col1 row1 component-sortable component-droppable ui-block-a" style="width:48%; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;" data-col="1" data-row="1">
  <style>
    label[for="checkbox-1"].ui-checkbox-on {}

    label[for="checkbox-1"].ui-checkbox-off {}

  </style>
  <div data-control-type="checkbox" data-control-id="checkbox-1" data-control-name="checkbox-1" data-object-column="A">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1" id="checkbox-1" data-theme="a">
    <label for="checkbox-1" data-translatable="Noise [A]">Noise [A]</label>
  </div>
```

Is there a possible way I can have a global variable (say of var test;) then when the radio button is checked, store the name of the label as test = label; (for instance). Then when it's removed, it will call the variable and empty it as the box has now been unchecked?

I've looked in to it a bit but can't find much, sorry for the basic q - I'm new to JS and taking on my own projects but seem to struggle with basic stuff.

Comment: What do you mean by alert out?

Answer (score 2):

Get the `text` of label when `checkbox` `.is(':checked')`

```js
var text = null;

$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {

  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    var text = $(this).next('label').text();
    alert(text);
  } else {
    alert(text);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-cell col1 row1 component-sortable component-droppable ui-block-a" style="width:48%; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;" data-col="1" data-row="1">
  <style>
    label[for="checkbox-1"].ui-checkbox-on {}
    
    label[for="checkbox-1"].ui-checkbox-off {}
  </style>
  <div data-control-type="checkbox" data-control-id="checkbox-1" data-control-name="checkbox-1" data-object-column="A">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1" id="checkbox-1" data-theme="a">
    <label for="checkbox-1" data-translatable="Noise [A]">Noise [A]</label>
  </div>
```

**Second Example:**

You can store name if checked or unchecked in an `array`:

```js
var store = new Array();

$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {

  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    var text = $(this).next('label').text();
    store.push(text);
  } else {
    var removeItem = $(this).next('label').text();

    store = $.grep(store, function(value) {
      return value != removeItem;
    });
  }

  console.log(store);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-cell col1 row1 component-sortable component-droppable ui-block-a" style="width:48%; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;" data-col="1" data-row="1">
  <style>
    label[for="checkbox-1"].ui-checkbox-on {}
    
    label[for="checkbox-1"].ui-checkbox-off {}
  </style>
  <div data-control-type="checkbox" data-control-id="checkbox-1" data-control-name="checkbox-1" data-object-column="A">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1" id="checkbox-1" data-theme="a">
    <label for="checkbox-1" data-translatable="Noise [A]">Noise [A]</label>
  </div>
```

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you - let's say I wanted to store it in a global variable of var test; then save it on the variable then clear it down once it's unchecked - is this possible?

Comment: @user9163418 You know what, it's better to say all you want in your question. But it's ok now, if i understand right, you want to collect all `name` in a global variable? on check and unchecked?

Comment: Sorry, I've literally just thought about doing it this way, let me update the question. So basically when the checkbox is checked, store the name in the variable, when it's unchecked, clear the name from the variable. @Mr. x

Comment: @user9163418 check the updated answer. Second example is with `array` first example with `variable`

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code

```js
var test = "";
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {

  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    test = $(this).next('label').text();
    console.log("test value: " + test)
  } else {
    test = "";
    console.log("test value: " + test)
  }

});
```

```css
body {
  font: 13px Verdana;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-cell col1 row1 component-sortable component-droppable ui-block-a" style="width:48%; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;" data-col="1" data-row="1">
  <div data-control-type="checkbox" data-control-id="checkbox-1" data-control-name="checkbox-1" data-object-column="A">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1" id="checkbox-1" data-theme="a">
    <label for="checkbox-1" data-translatable="Noise [A]">Noise [A]</label>
  </div>
</div>
```